# Reduce Mongo .wt File Size on live instance

Tags: mongodb, server, diskspace

I have a MongoDB 3.4.10 server running in production, and I'm starting to get really worried about maxing out my disk space on the machine. `df -k` indicates 99% utilization on `/var/vda1`.

If I run `sudo ncdu /` and browse the results it reveals that `/var/lib/mongodb/` is taking up 70.9 GiB, and 47.8 GiB of that is in a single file called `collection-0-7557246537050651683.wt`. I've tried deleting subsets of the stored documents from the database through the the `mongo` CLI, but that file doesn't seem to get any smaller. The remaining amount is taken up by a handful of `index-*.wt` files that are also 1 GiB+ each.

I would really like to get that file size reduced to give the server some breathing room *before* I run out of disk space, but I'm not sure what how to do that.

What should I do to resolve this situation, ideally without taking the server offline to do it?